# extract a partial string from a line in log file batch

Tags: batch-file

need to extarct partial string from a line in log file. I want to read a entries in log file, here is an example:

```
Thu 08/29/2019 10:46:43.22 setup.bat USB REIMAGE - WinPE reimage of .wim END
```

I want to extract only day, date and time

I have tried for loop to extract and it doesnot help me

```
For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In ("R:\reimage.log") Do Set "lastline=%%A"
    IF "%lastline%" == "USB REIMAGE - WinPE reimage of"(
    set lastline=!line:~0,4!
    echo "The last reimage performed by installer was on %lastline%"
    pause
)
```

Comment: is this the full string? `Thu 08/29/2019 10:46:43.22 setup.bat USB REIMAGE - WinPE reimage of .wim END`

Comment: yes...thats the full string

Comment: so in this string example you'll see how we use tokens. `for /f "tokens=1-3" %%i in ("Thu 08/29/2019 10:46:43.22 setup.bat USB REIMAGE - WinPE reimage of .wim END") do echo %%i %%j %%k`

Comment: i think i might not have asked correctly. i have log file in which i need to check if the last line of the file is setup.bat USB REIMAGE - WinPE reimage of .wim END. if this is the string, i need to extract date and time info

Comment: thanks much for input Gerhard... i got this working

Answer (score 0):

The example I gave in the comment was to show how we use tokens. Something like this should do what you want though:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%i in ('type R:\reimage.log ^| findstr /I "USB REIMAGE - WinPE"') do echo %%i %%j %%k
```

Comment: `findstr /ic:"USB REIMAGE - WinPE` or just `find /i "USB REIMAGE - WinPE"`